# Flex tree expand arrow click

Tags: apache-flex, tree, expand

In flex tree component is there a way to track the small expand arrow click. The itemClick event of the tree view doesn't execute for the expand arrow click.

[image]

Comment: when click arrow, tree fire 'itemOpen' or 'itemClose' event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track event "itemClose" and  "itemOpen" events. 
Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by creating a custom item renderer and disable the mouseEvents for the arrow icon (mouseChildren = false; mouseEnabled = false).

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to use http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/
It's having much more control (including the feature you are seeking), and better performance.